# Bloomberg function in Python (Works in Excel but not in python)

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

I have a question regarding building Bloomberg Functions in Python:

In Excel this works fine: =BDP(A1&" ISIN","SECURITY_NAME")

But how do i get it to work in python?

Comment: What have you tried, and with what result?

Comment: @DS_London tried this and it works: print(
    blp.bdp(
        tickers="SPX Index",
        flds=["SECURITY_NAME"],
    )
)

Comment: @DS_London but with an ISIN it doesnt work

Comment: My guess is that the Excel version is doing some extra parsing before sending the request to the underlying Bloomberg API. The API will understand `/ISIN/DE000BU2Z015`, and `DE000BU2Z015 Corp`, for a bond, but only `US0378331005 Equity` works for stock.

Comment: pip install xbbg

from xbbg import blp
blp.bdp("/ISIN/someisnnumber", "SECURITY_NAME")