# Bloomberg API bdp fuction with LEI (xbbg)

Tags: python, bloomberg

I try to pull 'Moodys credit rating' of entity using Python API.
Excel formula works well and Python using Tkcer also works well.
But Python using LEI not Tiker doesn't work.

For example, following two works well.

```
Excel formula : BDP("KNPC1X7GHDZW8U2ZSF89 LEI", "RTG_MDY_OUTLOOK") 
Python Xbbg : blp.bdp("1055z HK Equity", "RTG_MDY_OUTLOOK") 

(fyi, KNPC1X7GHDZW8U2ZSF89 and 1055z HK Equity are Bank of China HongKong Ltd)
```

But following doesn't work in Python xbbg.

```
blp.bdp("KNPC1X7GHDZW8U2ZSF89 LEI", "RTG_MDY_OUTLOOK")
```

Does `xbbg` not support LEI code?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76728778/15877695)

Comment: `/LEI/KNPC1X7GHDZW8U2ZSF89` works for me for the Moody's rating.